# Easiest distro and config to setup a headless server with odd hardware?

Tags: wifi, distributions, headless

I managed to get my hands on a surplus 1u rackmount server with oodles of CPU, memory, and HDD space. (Yay!  Time to play!) But I don't have any way to get into it!

It has a VGA port, and I've ordered the cheapo VGA to HDMI so I can at least see what it is thinking, it arrives in 3 weeks.  I have a generic USB WiFi dongle kicking around in a box somewhere.  And the server has ethernet.  (So much ethernet - 4 ports!).  No idea what sort of video capabilities beyond basic screen driver.

**I've only set up Raspberry PIs headless, and don't know which "normal" distro or config files are best for:**

1. Most likely to support a **wide range of hardware** (I'm guessing the RAID controller isn't that common)
2. Are most likely to be able to **identify and auto-use that USB WiFi dongle**
3. Could **auto-connect via config file** to my WiFi network, and expose a SSH port on my LAN so I could actually... do stuff.
4. Are **bootable from a USB stick** that I could drop off the WiFi PW into some config...

*DISCLAIMER: I hereby promise that I'm not stealth hacking a random server, it is actually my device now. :)*

Comment: This is probably an opinion question... so may get closed (FYI).
However, I suspect most Linux distros can do what you describe.  The few servers I've had experience with (all headless) were in cluster computers or HPC machines and those typically ran Red Hat or CentOS (mostly for long term stability).

Comment: Some hints: don't do RAID0 or RAID5. At all. Ever. If the disk controller card is a decent one you could possibly stack up RAID1, 10, or 6. But you might want to push it towards JBOD with ZFS anyway. It really depends on what you're going to do with the system. Finally, if you do use the controller card to set up your RAID, consider how you're going to handle card failure without losing all your data.